# Is there any character that is illegal in file paths on every OS?

Tags: windows, unix, character, filepath

Is there any character that is guaranteed not to appear in any file path on Windows or Unix/Linux/OS X?

I need this because I want to join together a few file paths into a single string, and then split them apart again later.

Comment: On Unix, only two characters are not allowed in a file name; the slash and the null (zero) byte.  The slash is not allowed because it separates components of a path from each other; the null because it marks the end of the name.  Therefore, the only character that's not allowed in a path name is the null byte.  I don't know of an O/S that allows the null byte in a file name; therefore, by reductio ad absurdam, the only character that is illegal in file paths on every O/S is the null byte.  Most people most of the time do not use control characters in file names, but they can appear.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: the Windows native API doesn't use null-terminated strings, so null is at least potentially a legal character.  I'm not certain whether the NTFS drivers actually allow this or not.  In practice this probably doesn't matter. :-)

Comment: @callum: the generic solution to this class of problem is to encode the file paths before joining them.  For example, if you're dealing with single-byte strings, you could convert them to hex strings; so "hello" becomes "68656c6c6f".  (Obviously that isn't the most efficient solution!)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: if the NUL byte is allowed in file names on Windows, then (a) I'm astonished and (b) there is no character that is guaranteed not to appear in any file path on Windows and Unix-like systems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I've just tried this out and on an NTFS volume an attempt to give a file a name with an embedded null was refused.  I believe this is file-system specific, so in theory embedded nulls could be allowed in alternate file systems.  (However, it seems unlikely that such a file system exists, or at least not in production!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, Harry Johnston writes:

> The generic solution to this class of problem is to encode the file paths before joining them. For example, if you're dealing with single-byte strings, you could convert them to hex strings; so "hello" becomes "68656c6c6f". (Obviously that isn't the most efficient solution!)

***That is absolutely correct.*** Please don't try to do anything "tricky" with filenames and reserved characters, because it *will* eventually break in some weird corner case and your successor will have a heck of a time trying to repair the damage.

In fact, if you're trying to be portable, I strongly recommend that you never attempt to create any filenames including *any* characters other than `[a-z0-9_]`. (Consider that common filesystems on both Windows and OS X can operate in case-insensitive mode, where `FooBar.txt` and `FOOBAR.TXT` are the same identifier.)

A decently compact encoding scheme for practical use would be to make a "whitelisted set" such as `[a-z0-9_]`, and encode any character `ch` outside your "whitelisted set" as `printf("_%2x", ch)`. So `hello.txt` becomes `hello_2etxt`, and `hello_world.txt` becomes `hello_5fworld_2etxt`.
Since every `_` is escaped, you can use double-`_` as a separator: the encoded string `hello_2etxt__goodbye___2e_2e` uniquely identifies the list of filenames `['hello.txt', 'goodbye', '..']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a newline character, or specifically CR (decimal code 13) or LF (decimal code 10) if you like. Whether this is suitable or not depends on what requirements you have with regard to displaying the concatenated string to the user - with this approach, it will print its parts on separate lines - which may be very good or very bad for the purpose (or you may not care...).

If you need the concatenated string to print on a single line, edit your question to specify this additional requirement; and we can go from there then.

Comment: With all due respect, while this answer covers the common cases, newlines are permitted in file names in Unix.  Depending on there not being a newline in the file name will eventually break.  That's why many of the GNU utilities now have an option that uses the null byte as the record separator for lists of files; it is the only character that cannot appear in a pathname, so it is strictly safe.  (See GNU `find` with `-print0`, `xargs` with `-0`, `sort` with `-z`, etc.)